# How to use audiere dll with MinGW

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker, mingw, name-mangling

I am building a project using wxWidgets compiled with MinGW g++ compiler. I was also using a component of the wxWidgets platform to play mp3 sound clips, but it has been unreliable so I went looking for another solution.  I found audiere and downloaded version 1.9.4 from their website.  The package contained a *.lib file and a *.dll.  I was trying to add this to my project but it doesn't work (I think because the package I downloaded was compiled in MSVC).

I created a *.def file using a tool called lib2a to convert from an MSVC lib to a .a lib I could use with MinGW.  The def file has these definitions...

> LIBRARY "audiere.dll"
>   EXPORTS
>   _AdrCreateLoopPointSource@4
>   _AdrCreateMemoryFile@8
>   _AdrCreatePinkNoise@0
>   _AdrCreateSampleBuffer@20
>   _AdrCreateSampleBufferFromSource@4
>   _AdrCreateSquareWave@8
>   _AdrCreateTone@8
>   _AdrCreateWhiteNoise@0
>   _AdrEnumerateCDDevices@0
>   _AdrGetSampleSize@4
>   _AdrGetSupportedAudioDevices@0
>   _AdrGetSupportedFileFormats@0
>   _AdrGetVersion@0
>   _AdrOpenCDDevice@4
>   _AdrOpenDevice@8
>   _AdrOpenFile@8
>   _AdrOpenMIDIDevice@4
>   _AdrOpenSampleSource@8
>   _AdrOpenSampleSourceFromFile@8
>   _AdrOpenSound@12
>   _AdrOpenSoundEffect@12

When I go to link my project I get the following errors:

> *** MinGWUnicodeRelease/AlphaPanel.o:AlphaPanel.cpp:(.text+0x8291): undefined reference to `_imp__AdrOpenDevice@8'
>   *** MinGWUnicodeRelease/AlphaPanel.o:AlphaPanel.cpp:(.text+0x82db): undefined reference to`*imp*_AdrOpenSampleSource@8'
>   *** MinGWUnicodeRelease/AlphaPanel.o:AlphaPanel.cpp:(.text+0x830f): undefined reference to `_imp__AdrOpenSound@12'
>   *** MinGWUnicodeRelease/AlphaPanel.o:AlphaPanel.cpp:(.text+0x87ce): undefined reference to`*imp*_AdrOpenDevice@8'
>   *** MinGWUnicodeRelease/AlphaPanel.o:AlphaPanel.cpp:(.text+0x8818): undefined reference to `_imp__AdrOpenSampleSource@8'
>   *** MinGWUnicodeRelease/AlphaPanel.o:AlphaPanel.cpp:(.text+0x884c): undefined reference to`*imp*_AdrOpenSound@12'

In my code for example the function is "OpenDevice"...in the def file it is >"_AdrOpenDevice@8", but in my undefined references link error it is "*imp*_AdrOpenDevice@8".  So my head is spinning and not sure what to do at this point.

Is there an easy way to fix the name mangling problem in the dll?

Perhaps to edit it with a binary editor to "fix" the names and get this to work with my existing code (short of downloading the entire audiere code to recompile and create the dll [if possible] using MinGW...I want to avoid this if I can)...my starting point is a *.lib file and a dll created in MSVC, but I need to use it in MinGW.

Anybody have any clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to use audiere with Windows....(this is my solution, but you might find this useful as a starting point if you want to use this and you need to do something similar)...

I get a whole bunch of warning messages about to do with having virtual functions but not having a virtual destructor...don't know how to get rid of these, but it still works.

1) Download binaries for 1.9.4 package for windows
2) From this package, you only need 3 files. audiere.h, audiere.dll and audiere.lib which are in different directories.
3) Rename audiere.lib to audiere.a
4) Copy audiere.dll to the same directory where your executable will run from so it can be found at runtime.
5) Copy audiere.a to linker directory and add it to the file list in the project.
6) Copy audiere.h to your source directory where all your other *.h files are.
7) In the *.h file of your source code, add #include "audiere.h" (note not )
8) Also in the *.h file, add the following as global variables (I don't use namespaces so I specify the fully qualified name)

```
audiere::AudioDevicePtr device;
audiere::OutputStreamPtr sound;
```

9) In your *.cpp file, in the constructor, add the following:

```
device = audiere::OpenDevice();
```

10) Add a timer so you can monitor the when the sound clip finishes playing.  For me, it fires 4 times a second.  When the clip is finished, the timer is stopped.  Here is my code:

```
void MyClass::OnTimerEvent( wxTimerEvent& event )
{
   bool restartTimer = true;
   bool isItPlaying;

   timer.Stop();
   isItPlaying = sound -> isPlaying();
   // check status of audio clip

   if (isItPlaying == false)
      timer.Start(250);
   else {
      // re-enable any controls you disabled while audio clip was playing

   } // end else
} // end OnTimerEvent
```

11) In your code where you actually want to kick off (load and play) the sound clip - add something like this:

(note you need char_str method to pull it out of a wxString object)

```
fileName.sprintf(wxT("c:\\testsound.mp3"));
sound = audiere::OpenSound(device, fileName.char_str(), true);
sound -> play();
timer.Start(250);
```

12) Suppose you already have the clip loaded and want to play it again without reloading it.  In that case, just repeat the last two lines from step 11 (sound -> play(); and timer.Start(250);)

In a nutshell that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Beg pardon, but in *which* *.h file of your source code? :)  Might be helpful to tell people which files to work with.